# How to access a variable up the callstack in Go

Tags: go, runtime

Preface: I understand this is a questionable idea, but imagine a situation where I control the beginning and end of a callstack, but don't control some intermediate functions.

I'm looking to "recover" a `context.Context` that existed further up the callstack, but was omitted on its way down to the current runtime location.  What would be a way to do this?

How far have I gotten?
I can get an arbitrary frame up the callstack with the below code:

```golang
pc := make([]uintptr, 15)
n := runtime.Callers(2, pc) // skip the Callers frame, and this current frame
frames := runtime.CallersFrames(pc[:n])
frame, _ := frames.Next()
```

which buys me access to a runtime [`Frame`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Frame) [(source)](https://golang.org/src/runtime/symtab.go?s=647:1923#L15), but nothing else.  Access to its internal [`_func`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/runtime2.go#L776) may be useful, but here's where I'm stuck

Comment: Is the value that you are trying to access is one that you had with you at the beginning or, it is result of intermediate functions? Is end of call stack is called by intermediate functions and not by your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**WARNING!**

This is something possible and I'll show you in a bit, but before you'd go ahead and grab the presented solution, you should be screaming and protest against it with everything you got. Refactor! Do not ever do this in production code, it's fragile and it's not protected by [Go's compatibility promise](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat)!

---

Now simply for educational purposes let's see how something like this can be done.

What you want is basically access a *variable* whose declaration is neither global (or more precisely package level in Go) nor local to the function, but it's somewhere higher in the call stack. This is called *dynamic scoping*. The solution below builds on the solution presented by Dave Cheney in his [Dynamically scoped variables](https://dave.cheney.net/2019/12/08/dynamically-scoped-variables-in-go) blog post.

For demonstration let's assume there's an `f1()` function which receives a `ctx context.Context`, and it calls `f2()` without passing the context. And we want to access the context of `f1` in `f2()`. Something like this:

```
func f1(ctx context.Context) {
    // Does something with ctx
    f2()
}

func f2() {
    ctx := getCtx() // We desperately need context here!!!
    // Do something with ctx
}
```

The big question is: how can `getCtx()` be implemented?

First let's try the following program:

```
func main() {
    f1(context.Background())
}

func f1(ctx context.Context) {
    fmt.Println(ctx)
    f2()
}

func f2() {
    panic("")
}
```

This will output (try it the Go Playground):

```
context.Background
panic: 

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.f2(...)
    /tmp/sandbox870956446/prog.go:18
main.f1(0x4e7000, 0xc00002c008)
    /tmp/sandbox870956446/prog.go:14 +0x9b
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox870956446/prog.go:9 +0x3
```

If you look at the stack trace, especially this line:

```
main.f1(0x4e7000, 0xc00002c008)
```

It contains the function call to `main.f1()` and its argument(s)! `f1` has a single parameter of type `context.Context`, so what's this?

In Go internally interfaces are represented by 2 pointers, one to the type descriptor of the dynamic value stored in it, and another one to the dynamic value stored in it. These are the 2 pointers you see printed.

The idea is to grab these 2 pointers, and construct a `context.Context` interface value from them. How to do that?

It can only be done by importing package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) (yes, using it is unsafe!). We can construct an array of type `[2]uintptr`, load these 2 values into it, and convert it to `context.Context` like this:

```
idata := [2]uintptr{p1, p2}
*(*context.Context)(unsafe.Pointer(&idata))
```

Without further ado, here's the `getCtx()` implementation:

```
func getCtx() context.Context {
    var buf [8192]byte
    n := runtime.Stack(buf[:], false)
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader(buf[:n]))
    for sc.Scan() {
        var p1, p2 uintptr
        n, _ := fmt.Sscanf(sc.Text(), "main.f1(%v, %v", &p1, &p2)
        if n != 2 {
            continue
        }

        idata := [2]uintptr{p1, p2}
        return *(*context.Context)(unsafe.Pointer(&idata))
    }
    return nil
}
```

Let's construct a quick app to test it:

```
func main() {
    testContexts := []context.Context{
        context.Background(),
        context.TODO(),
    }
    for i, ctx := range testContexts {
        fmt.Printf("[%d] In main(): %p\n", i, ctx)
        f1(ctx)
    }
}

func f1(ctx context.Context) {
    fmt.Printf("In f1(): %p\n", ctx)
    f2()
}

func f2() {
    ctx := getCtx()
    fmt.Printf("In f2(): %p\n", ctx)
}
```

Running it will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/j8tl9do5wSn)):

```
[0] In main(): 0xc00002c008
In f1(): 0xc00002c008
In f2(): 0xc00002c008
[1] In main(): 0xc00002c020
In f1(): 0xc00002c020
In f2(): 0xc00002c020
```

As you can see, we could acquire the same context that was passed to `f1` in `f2()` without the context being passed to it.